# How do I mock a nest method call in a Laravel test?

Tags: php, laravel

In my model I have the following:

```php
// app/Model/Account.php

class Account extends Model {

    public function createTwilioSubaccount(){

        $TwilioAdminCli = TwilioRestClient::AsAdminAccount();
        $subAccount = $TwilioAdminCli->api->v2010
            ->accounts
            ->create(["friendlyName" => $this->uid]);
    
    // ...
    
    }

}
```

In my test, `createTwilioSubaccount()` is triggered by:

```php
\App\Models\VideoCallApp::factory()->create();
```

How do I mock the response of

`$TwilioAdminCli->api->v2010->accounts->create(["friendlyName" => $this->uid])`

Answer (score 0):

Laravel documentation say:

That you should mock your object TwilioAdminCli::class

```
$mock = $this->mock(TwilioAdminCli::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('api')->once()->with(??)->andReturn(file.json??);
});
```

Observe, chained methods with(). andReturn(file.json??)